# ことになっている vs ようになっている

Tags: grammar

The definitions do not help with an umabiguous separation.
So I put forward an example:
      どあはしめると,じどうしゃてきにかぎがかかる**ようになっている**
Why would `ことになっている` **too** not be apt here?
Is this dependent on the speakers perception - whether he believes an event/activity happens as part of a previous arrangement/decision;or a natural/spontaneous phenomenon.
In the above sentence - the act of the key turning automatically on the closing of the door can be interpreted either way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“するようになっている” means that something is designed to do something,
while “することになっている” means that someone or something have to do something.

> ○　ドアは閉めると、自動的に鍵がかかる**ようになっている**。
>   ×　ドアは閉めると、自動的に鍵がかかる**ことになっている**。
>
> ○　彼はここに来る**ことになっている**。
>   ×　彼はここに来る**ようになっている**。